# Rename a file which is used by the Swing component

Tags: java, swing, file, file-rename

How to rename any file which is used by the swing component?

I'm working on a project where i have to rename a file which is loaded in `JList` and the file is used by the `JPanel`. I have tried very hard to rename file but I failed every time. So please help me to rename the file or tell me some file locking concept to rename the file.

Comment: can you please post your code here?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If you are using the File.renameTo method, replace it with [Files.move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29).  It may not work any better, but you will get an informative exception if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
f.renameTo(f1);
```

here f is an old file and f1 is a new file. Specify new path to f1.

Answer (score 0):

Most possibly that you use Windows and after reading from the file into JList/JPanel you didn't close the file (keep the handle open). Close the file and rename it, then re-open it. On other OSes (Linux/OS X) you will be able to rename the file even if it's used by your component. But I guess your java app should be cross-platform.

Comment: i have tried this but it didn't work. I have tried another logic to create a new file with new name it works but the old file couldn't deleted.